# Преобразование в строку

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Есть скрипт:

```
def extract(filePath):

    f = open(filePath, 'rb')

    i = 0

    lines = []

    for line in f:
        print(line)
        line = str(line)
        if line == 'PlAr\n':
            break
        lines.append(line.split('\t'))

        i += 1
    return lines[13:len(lines)-1]
```

Проблема в том что, когда line преобразовывается в строку, то появляется буква "b" в начале каждой строки, например, в файле строка была 'text', а после преобразования стало 'b"text"'. Помимо символа b ещё и кавычки появляются.
Вообщем, как сделать чтобы строка преобразовывалась без символа и кавычек?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы открываете в режиме бинарного чтения (`rb`), поэтому возвращаются байты, у них литерал `b''`, а когда вы применяете к байтам `str` то получаете текстовое представление этого типа.

Решения:

- Открывать в текстовом режиме чтения:

  ```
  f = open(filePath, 'r')
  ```

  Но, возможно, понадобится указывать кодировку файла, например:

  ```
  f = open(filePath, 'r', encoding='utf8')
  ```
- Либо оставить как есть и сделать перевод из байтов в строку, например:

  ```
  line = str(line, encoding='utf-8')
  ```

  или так:

  ```
  line = line.decode('utf-8')
  ```

Comment: Получилось только с указанием кодировки.

Answer (score 1):

Открыть файл как текстовый, а не бинарный

```
f = open(filePath, 'r')
```

Comment: Изначально так и было сделано, когда работало на винде, но на линуксе я получаю ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Декодировать полученную строку:

```
line.decode('utf-8') # можно и просто line.decode() по умолчанию utf-8
```

либо окрыть файл как текcтовый 'r', а не бинарный 'rb'.